# Oracle regexp to ignore repeating characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I've a string like:

`hheelllloo wwoorrlldd !!`
that should return `hello world!`

and my try for the above is

```
SELECT regexp_substr('hheelllloo wwoorrlldd !!', '.', LEVEL*2-1)l_val
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('hheelllloo wwoorrlldd !!')/2;
```

But its not the way i needed and the logic is not correctly used.
I've also tried using `'(\w)\1'`

My expected result in a sample data:

```
WITH t AS
     ( SELECT 'hheelllloo wwoorrlldd!!' AS word FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'hellow world!' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'ootthheerrss' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 'ootthheeerrss' FROM dual
     )
SELECT * FROM t;
```

output should looks like:

```
 hello world!    --expression applied
 hellow world!     -- not needed for non-repeated characters
 others           --expression applied
 otheers          --applied and extra `e` considered as non-repeated.
```

Can I make the whole in a single query., or the first one?
Thanks in advance and this is only for my practice and to know different logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()` regular expression function with back reference:

```
SQL> WITH t1(col) AS (
  2    select 'hheelllloo wwoorrlldd!!' from dual union all
  3    select 'hellow world!'           from dual union all
  4    select 'ootthheerrss'            from dual union all
  5    select 'ootthheeerrss'           from dual
  6  )
  7  select regexp_replace(col, '(.)\1', '\1') as res
  8    from t1
  9  ;

RES
--------------
hello world!
helow world!
others
otheers
```

Comment: Thats percent..!! I think we can't make `hellow` as `hellow` itself right?!

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 double `l` is considered to be repeated in this case.

Comment: yeah, so the above can only be used for the words that are not repeating, `full`, `balloon` etc cannot be used :D

Answer (score 0):

```
And
select regexp_replace('A;A;B;B', '(.)\1', '\1')
from `dual`
```

Output:

```
A;B ????????
```

I have this answer.